# Concacenate several text files (with Windows batch + sed) which have their name matching one of a specific pattern (stored in a Windows text file)

Tags: batch-file, sed

I would like to concacenate several text files which have their name that matches a specific pattern, (patterns are stored in a text file).

One file named `patterns.cfg` contains the searching match patterns (one per line); those lines beginning with the character `#` are to be ignored:

```
CS_*.csv
#MV_*.csv
TRA_*.txt
```

So here, only `CS_\*.csv` and `TRA_\*.txt` are valid patterns to be used.

I need a batch file that loads that patterns from the `patterns.cfg` file and concacenate, all the files stored in "Data" subdirectory that match these patterns, into one file.

I have the Windows 10 batch file on my PC, plus the gnuwin32 sed executable.

I tried to do this with the following batch file but I can't make it work:

```bash
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%u in ('.\GnuWin32\bin\sed "s/^#.*\r\n//g" Tags_Data_Med_lst.prm ^| .\GnuWin32\bin\sed "s/\r\n/\\\|/g"') do set patterns=%%u

echo off > output.csv

for %%f in (.\Data\%patterns%) do type "%%f" >> output.csv
```

Comment: Have you tried just a single line batch file, ```@(For /F "UseBackQ EOL=# Delims=" %%G In ("P:\athTo\patterns.cfg") Do @Type "%%~G") 1>"P:\athTo\output.csv"```? As you can see, there's no need for using a stream editor, the functionality for omitting lines beginning with a specific character is already an option in a `For /F` command.

Comment: Thank you for your help Compo. It seems ok, but I can't see how to manage the fact that the "patterns.cfg" file (which contains the search patterns) is in "." directory, whereas the directory where it has to search the files that match these patterns is "./Data/". Could you help me a bit more ?

Comment: How do you know what `.` resolves to. It's supposed to be a relative path ior the current directory, but there's currently nothing in your code or explanation to tell me where or how that is being determined. If you can guarantee that the current directory is always the one holding the `patterns.cfg` file then perhaps you could use ```@(For /F "UseBackQ EOL=# Delims=" %%G In (".\patterns.cfg") Do @Type ".\Data\%%~G") 1>".\output.csv"```. Although none of those relative paths are really needed: ```@(For /F "UseBackQ EOL=# Delims=" %%G In ("patterns.cfg") Do @Type "Data\%%~G") 1>"output.csv"```